# Django allauth - can I disable redirects after Social logins?

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I would like to disable redirects after Social logins in django allauth, i.e. if a user is on page 'X' (and not logged in), then chooses to log in (via ajax request), they should remain on page 'X' (no reload/redirect etc.).

This functionality would be similar to the normal Account setting, i.e.
'ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATED_LOGIN_REDIRECTS = False'

As far as I know there isn't a '**SOCIAL**ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATED_LOGIN_REDIRECTS' setting available.